# Why is my enum saying "ErrorType"

Tags: swift, enums, xcode9

```
class Question {
    var type: QuestionType
    var query: String
    var answer: String

    init(type: QuestionType, query: String, answer: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.query = query
        self.answer = answer
    }
}


enum QuestionType: String {
    case trueFalse = "The sky is blue."
    case multipleChoice = "Who is the ugliest Beatle: John, Paul, George or Ringo?"
    case shortAnswer = "What is the capital of Oregon?"
    case essay = "In 50 words, explain moleceular fusion"

    static let types = [trueFalse, multipleChoice, shortAnswerm, essay]
}

enum AnswerType: String {
    case trueFalse = "true"
    case multipleChoice = "Sgt. Pepper"
    case shortAnswer = "Salem"
    case essay = "Molecular fusion happens when a daddy molecule and a mommy molecule love each other very much"

    static let types = [trueFalse, multipleChoice, shortAnswerm, essay]
}


protocol QuestionGenerator {
    func generateRandomQuestion() -> Question
}

class Quiz: QuestionGenerator {
    func generateRandomQuestion() -> Question {
        let randomNumeral = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
        let randomType = QuestionType.types[randomNumeral]
        let randomQuery = randomType.rawValue
        let randomAnswer = AnswerType.types[randomNumeral].rawValue
        let randomQuestion = Question(type: randomType, query: randomQuery, answer: randomAnswer)
        return randomQuestion
    }
}
```

when I mouse over **let randomAnswer = AnswerType.types[randomNumeral].rawValue**, I see a popover that shows Error Type. I don't understand why Playground thinks there is an error

Comment: I copy paste your code in playground and the only error I see is the character 'm' at the end of 'shortAnswerm' in 'static let types' for both of your enum. Other than that everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy paste your code in playground and the only error I see is the character 'm' at the end of 'shortAnswerm' in 'static let types' for both of your enum. Other than that everything is ok